# How do I interact with a loaded php file?

Tags: php, jquery, click, load

```
$('#offer').click(function() {
    $("<br><br><strong>Please wait...</strong>").appendTo($("#results"));
    $('#results').load("fulfill.php");

});

$("#employees tr").live("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).find('id').attr('id');
    alert(id);
```

I have a dynamic table that is in the fulfill.php file.  When it loads, I want to be able to click on any of the rows and get the id value.  It loads fine and I can click with a response.  I cannot get the id value.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
 var id = $(this).find('id').attr('id');
```

to

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

If you want the ID of the `tr`.

And you should consider using [$.on](http://api.jquery.com/on) as $.live is depreciated now.